# How to apply function element wise to 2D tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, torch

Very simple question but I have been struggling with this forever now.

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor([[2,3],[4,6]])
overlap = [2, 6]
f = lambda x: x in overlap
```

I want:

```
torch.tensor([[True,False],[False,True]])
```

Both the tensor and overlap are very big, so efficiency is wished here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an easy way. Since torch is implemented through numpy array the following works and is performant:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
t = torch.tensor([[2,3],[4,6]])
overlap = [2, 6]
f = lambda x: x in overlap
mask = np.vectorize(f)(t)
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594695/how-to-apply-a-function-map-values-of-each-element-in-a-2d-numpy-array-matrix).

Answer (score 1):

The native way to do this is using `torch.Tensor.apply_` method:

```py
t.apply_(f)
```

However according to [official doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.apply_.html) it only works for tensors on CPU and discouraged for reaching high performance.

Besides it seems that there is not native torch function indicating if values of tensors are in a list and the only option should be to iterate over the list `overlap`. See [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/check-if-tensor-elements-in-a-value-list/67923) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036375/how-to-check-whether-tensor-values-in-a-different-tensor-pytorch). Thus you can try:

```py
sum(t==i for i in overlap).bool()
```

I found that the second function is more performant for big `t` and `overlap` and the first one for small `t` and `overlap`.

Comment: I figured, that there is no function for this, I am wondering why what is. Because for example, we do have atomic operations such as `add` which can be applied element wise. I don't understand why there exists no general function .. maybe I will have a look in the code how these are implemented.